# Placement of additional elements in a complex image

Tags: composition

I'm creating a map/graph/diagram and I would like to add a graph to indicate the relative strength of different industries (three sector model). The same picture already contains the economic development, start and end values, name and map in the background, so I am running out of space to place a circle diagram for the industries. Any suggestions as where it would be nice and readable?

The side borders of the image are pretty fixed, so putting it next to the name of the province is not really feasible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram is heavily formatted for each countries data being in a list.

If you are going to add data for each country it can only be in this list. If there are 3 industry factors for each country perhaps you can add 3 numbers to each countries data.

Your little line graphs are ineffective as they all look the same and tell the same growth story. Maybe to make room you can reduce or remove these elements. The line graphs can be replaced by a numerical percentage change (+360%) so "Hainan: 248-6526  +2600%  80 67 41" with those last 3 numbers being the 3 industry factors. These can be color coded and explained in the legend or labeled on each factor.

I put this as an answer and not a comment because my comment was too long.